# Structuring a long SQL statement with pg - nodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have been performing some simple queries with `pg` and nodejs, can fit on one line, like so

```
async function update_match_count(value, id){
  (async () => {
    const client = await pool.connect();
    try {
      const res = await client.query('UPDATE fixtures SET hh_match_count = ($1) WHERE id = ($2) RETURNING *', [value, id]);
    } finally {
      client.release()
    }
  })().catch(e => console.log(e.stack))
}
```

Now I have a scenario where my query is somewhat complex and spans over many lines

```
await client.query('SELECT CAST((CASE WHEN coalesce(hh_total_fhc_0,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN coalesce(hh_total_fhc_1,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN coalesce(hh_total_fhc_2,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN coalesce(hh_total_fhc_3,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN coalesce(hh_total_fhc_4,0) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +)AS DECIMAL)/ hh_match_count * 100 FROM fixtures WHERE id = ($1)', [id]);
```

So there are two reasons why I don't want to continue like this

1) It doesn't work (I get a syntax error warning)

2) It is not readable.

Can I separate this out over multiple lines without getting syntax issues ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use backticks instead of quotes to make a multiline string : `\`` and then use templates to concatenate (if needed): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thanks, problem solved